# snprintf in a loop does not work on linux

Tags: c, linux

`snprintf` in a loop does not work on `linux` but it works properly on `windows`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main( int argc, char **argv) {
      char buffer[255] ={0};
      for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        snprintf(buffer, 255, "%s:%x\0",buffer,  i );
      }
      printf ( "BUFFER  = %s\n", buffer );
      return 0;
    }
```

This code does not append existing `buffer` but only takes the last iteration value.

Comment: Just a guess that printing `buffer` to `buffer` is undefined, so just seems to work, sometimes.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes, yes on windows it append to the buffer

Comment: @Avinash so Windows is crappy and doesn't obey standards (again) while Linux does. UNIX powwa!

Comment: @H2CO3 No. *This code* doesn't obey standards. Neither of the implementations (this is not about OSes, but about C library implementations) is wrong.

Comment: If you want to append, use the `strcat` function instead. Also note that you don't need to explicitly add the string terminator `'\0'`, it's added automatically.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I didn't say this code isn't wrong, I answered that this is undefined behavior. But Windows is acting out a DS9k in this case...

Comment: `255` is a very odd number for a buffer size...

Comment: @H2CO3: Since the code is UB, *any* implementation is acceptable. It's literally impossible for any implementation to not be obeying the Standard in this case.

Comment: @DeadMG OK you won, I don't want to get into a flamewar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid the undefined behavior of using the buffer both as the target string and as an argument like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv) {
  char buffer[255] ={0};
  int offset = 0;
  for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    offset += snprintf(buffer + offset, 255 - offset, ":%x\0", i);
  }
  printf ( "BUFFER  = %s\n", buffer );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Beware that with more than 10 iterations, you could overflow the buffer. I feel that the `255` argument to your `snprintf` is wrong.

Comment: It should probably be `255 - (offset - buffer)`, or something like that.

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch and Kerrek SB: Thanks for the remarks. I've updated my answer.

Comment: You'll need to `break` the loop when `offset >= sizeof(buffer)`

Comment: Also beware that `snprintf()` will return negative numbers in case of error. You don't want to add negative values to `offset`.

Answer (score 3):

`sprintf()`'ing the result array to itself is undefined behaviour.

EDIT: if you want some code that works, here you are: use `strcat()` (or the safer strncat, etc. insert usual security discussion about buffer overflow here):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv) {
    char buffer[255] = { 0 };
    char fmtbuf[64];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        snprintf(fmtbuf, 64, "%x", fmtbuf, i);
        strcat(buffer, fmtbuf);
    }

    printf ("BUFFER  = %s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that printf() calls don't need the terminating zero to be written out manually -- it's automatically added.

Answer (score 1):

[snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) does work as specified on Linux, but your code does not append it. Read the *Note* in the linked documentation!

You should not use as its arguments (after the format string) the destination.

If you want it to append, either ensure that you don't overflow your fixed buffer, or reallocate that buffer when it gets too small.

Answer (score 0):

You could not write 'buffer' to itself by 'snprintf'.

The test code is as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>

int main( int argc, char **argv) {
    char buffer[255] ={0};
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char tmp[255] = {0};
        strcpy(tmp, buffer);
        snprintf(buffer, 255, "%s:%x\0",tmp,  i );
        printf ( "BUFFER  = %s\n", buffer );
        }
    printf ( "BUFFER  = %s\n", buffer );  
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard specifically states that this code is not expected to work.  Firstly, the initial buffer argument is declared `restrict`, which means that it cannot alias another argument.  Secondly, the standard has the following clause just for emphasis:

> [c99](/questions/tagged/c99)
>
> ### 7.19.6.5 The snprintf function
>
> #### Description
>
> 2 - [...] If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undeﬁned.